# PowerBI Semantic Models

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

So my client has these two reports that's using identical data and measures but different semantic models published in PowerBI. Question is, would it be entirely possible to change the existing data source of report # 2 to the published semantic model of report # 1? If so, I am aware that modelling on report 2 will then be disabled but will it have any other effects other than the previously mentioned?